# What does "analytical design" mean?

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, optimal-control, feedback-loop

What is meant by "designing analytically" ?
Especially in control systems design

Does it mean theoretically design?

Answer (score 1):

I would think that this refers to using mathematical and physical principles and equations to predict the behaviour of a control system.

The opposite would be to empirically design a control system, by implementing it and measuring it.